# c# asking multiple questions in a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am very confused, this is only my second project in coding/scripting and i do not understand how to have multiple choices for a player to choose between. the loop goes back after the second or third question without continuing and it keeps skipping a few lines of code just wondering what I am doing wrong.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int stuff = 0;
        bool gameGo = true;
        string yourAnswer = "";
        string choice1 = "";
        string choice2 = "";
        string choice3 = "";
        string choice4 = "";
        int healthPoints = 100;
        int deathNumber = rng.Next(0, 10);
        deathNumber = deathNumber = 0;
        int stabbed = rng.Next(1, 4);
        string name = "";
        int trap = rng.Next(1, 5);
        int arrow = rng.Next(7, 14);
        int menu = 0;
        int potion = rng.Next(1, 10);
        int flyHealth = rng.Next(5, 10);
        int flyAttack = rng.Next(3, 5);
        int tribeAttack = rng.Next(80, 100);
        int playersSword = rng.Next (3, 5);
        while(true)
        {
            break;
        }
 while (gameGo || stuff == 1 )
 {

 Console.Write("You have ");
 Console.Write(healthPoints);
 Console.Write(", health points left");
 Console.Write(" \nIf your health points drops to ");
 Console.Write(deathNumber);
 Console.Write(", you will DIE!");
 Console.WriteLine("\nWell now that that's out of the way, excuse me for being so rude but,\nmay i have your name? Please hit enter after to continue.");
 name = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.Clear();


 if (name == "Dustin")
 {
     Console.Write("You have");
     Console.Write(healthPoints);
     Console.Write(", health points left");
     Console.WriteLine("\nI am so proud of you for figuring out your name, {0}", name);
     Console.WriteLine("Shall we move on to the story?\n Hit Enter to continue.");
     Console.ReadLine();
     menu = 2;

 }

 else if (name != "Dustin")
 {
     healthPoints -= stabbed;
     Console.Clear();
     Console.WriteLine("Seriously you cant figure out your name, how dumb are you?");

 }
 if (menu == 2)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You see a cave in the distance.");
     Console.WriteLine(" You have to make a choice.");
     Console.WriteLine("Do you go in to explore or do you pass on by?");
     Console.WriteLine("a) Do you go in\nOr B) do you pass by?");
     choice1 = Console.ReadLine();


 }
 if (choice1 == "a")
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You enter a dark cave with no idea where to go but you found a sword.");
     Console.WriteLine("The sword can do 1-5 damage.\n This is your only defense.");
     Console.Write("\nTap enter once to continue");
     Console.ReadLine();
     menu = 3;
     Console.Clear();
 }
 if (choice1 == "b")
 {
     Console.WriteLine("What, are you scared of the dark?");
     healthPoints -= stabbed;
     Console.WriteLine("A masked man stabbed you for not going in the cave and says");
     Console.Write("you now have,");
     Console.Write(healthPoints);
     Console.Write(" health points left");
     Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue.");
     Console.ReadLine();
     menu = 4;
     continue; 
 }
 {
     while (menu == 3)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You wander further in the cave and look around");
         Console.WriteLine("You see a torch on the wall");
         Console.WriteLine("You have another choice.\nDo you a) Light the torch \n or b) Leave it unlit");
         choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Clear();
     }
     if (choice2 == "a")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Well done my good sir, you have brought light to this wretched cave.");
         Console.WriteLine("You move along slowly and encounter a giant fly.");
         Console.Clear();
         menu = 5;

     }
     if (choice2 == "b")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("What do you enjoy being in the dark?");
         healthPoints -= stabbed;
         Console.WriteLine("A masked man snuck up on you and stabbed you in the dark");
         Console.Write("you now have,");
         Console.Write(healthPoints);
         Console.Write(" health points left");
         Console.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine("You move along slowly in the dark and encounter a giant fly.");
         Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Clear();
         menu = 6;
     }
 }
 {
     while (menu == 4)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You chose to keep walking along and not go into the cave.");
         Console.WriteLine("You stumble across a large valley.");
         Console.WriteLine("Time for another choice.");
         Console.WriteLine("Do you a) Climb down the valley hoping for cool treasure?\nOR b) Keep walking along?");
         choice3 = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Clear();
     }

     if (choice3 == "a")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You decided to go into the valley");
         Console.WriteLine("Little did you know there was a trap that got sprung as you climbed down");
         healthPoints -= trap;
         Console.Clear();
         menu = 7;

     }
     if (choice3 == "b")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("How much more boring can you get, do you ever go on real adventures.");
         Console.WriteLine("as you are walking along a stray arrow comes out of no where and strikes you in the leg.");
         healthPoints -= arrow;
         Console.Clear();
         menu = 8;
     }
 }
 {
     while (menu == 5)
     {
         //giant fly fight
         Console.Write("The giant fly swoops in to attack");
         flyAttack -= healthPoints;
         Console.WriteLine("The fly does {0} damage to your health", flyAttack);
         Console.Write("You now have,");
         Console.Write(healthPoints);
         Console.Write(" health.");
         Console.WriteLine("You attack back, with your sword you found");
         playersSword -= flyHealth;
         Console.WriteLine("You did {0} damage to the flys health points.", playersSword);
         menu = 9;


     }
     while (menu == 6)
     {
         Console.Write("The giant fly swoops in to attack");
         flyAttack -= healthPoints;
         Console.WriteLine("The fly does {0} damage to your health", flyAttack);
         Console.Write("You now have,");
         Console.Write(healthPoints);
         Console.Write(" health.");
         Console.WriteLine("You attack back, with your sword you found");
         playersSword -= flyHealth;
         Console.WriteLine("You did {0} damage to the flys health points.", playersSword);
         menu = 9;
     }
     while (menu == 7)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You reach the bottom and come across a tribe of people.");
         Console.WriteLine("This tribe has never seen another human before.");
         Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue.");
         Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Clear();
         Console.WriteLine("You hesitate for a bit wondering what to do. \nWhen all of a sudden the tribe attacks.");
         healthPoints -= tribeAttack;
         Console.Write("You have ");
         Console.Write(healthPoints);
         Console.Write(", health points left");

     }
     if (menu == 8)
     {
         //kept walking 
     }
     if (menu == 9)
     {
```

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] topic you should have seen during tour of the site, and edit your question according to linked guidance, pay close attention to "minimal" part of it.

Comment: Additionally, if you're not comfortable with a debugger yet, take some time to learn how to use one. The debugger build into Visual Studio is quite easy and intuitive to use. You'll be able to answer this type of question for yourself by stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger.

Comment: okay thanks ill look again and the debugger picks nothing up

Comment: I just dont understand why it works for the first two questions/choices then it seems to skip a few sections to the last option, then loops back to the start. without reading any of the menu=# but it worked for the first few. ive even rewritten this multiple times plus a few places where i wrote "hit enter to continue" it doesnt even read that line at all.

Comment: example is this one

Comment: Console.WriteLine("You enter a dark cave with no idea where to go but you found a sword.");
     Console.WriteLine("The sword can do 1-5 damage.\n This is your only defense.");
     Console.WriteLine("Tap enter once to continue");
     Console.ReadLine();
     menu = 3;
     Console.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

`while` loops happen until a condition is satisfied.

Something written like this (which is taken from your example above) will never stop.

```
while (menu == 3 {
    // do stuff here, but menu never changes
}
```

The loop is entered when `menu` is 3. `menu` is never changed from within the loop, so it will never change from 3 - thus the loop will never exit. It will simply start back at the beginning of the loop until `menu` is not 3.

For further clarification, `if` statements cause code to be executed based on a condition. Unlike a `while` loop, the block of code that is executed is not looped through. If the condition is false, no code within the block is executed. If the condition is true, the code within the block is only executed once.

You'll be able to make some progress once you think about how things flow. To help with this, if you're using a modern IDE, you can set a breakpoint at the beginning and step through the program, watching how decisions are made one line at a time.